# How to set loop for Selenium webdriver in Python

Tags: python-3.x, loops, selenium-webdriver

I have code example down bellow that I want to run from **driver.get** to the last **driver.find_element_by_** 'till I close it.

How can I set up simple loop? It can be endless for now as the code will change eventually with "for, if".

```
class AppDynamicsJob(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome
        self.base_url = "https://www.google.com/"
        self.verificationErrors = []
        self.accept_next_alert = True

    def test_app_dynamics_job(self):
        driver = self.driver
# loop will start here
        driver.get("https://yahoo.com/")
        driver.find_element_by_xpath("").click()
        driver.find_element_by_id("").click()
        driver.find_element_by_id("").clear()
# jump to the beginning of the loop
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, honestly, I just needed some sleep:

```
def test_app_dynamics_job(self):
        for i in range(100):
           driver = self.driver
           driver.get("https://yahoo.com/")
           driver.find_element_by_xpath("").click()
           driver.find_element_by_id("").click()
           driver.find_element_by_id("").clear()
```